# Selecting multiple fields using If condition, with left join in mysql - throwing error

Tags: mysql, if-statement, left-join, conditional-statements

Any help is appreciated  --

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as receiverimage, re.fName as receiverfName , re.lName as receiverlName , re.add' at line

```
SELECT co.*, 
if(( co.senderid = 1) , ( re.image as receiverimage, re.fName as receiverfName , re.lName as receiverlName , re.address as receiverAddress , re.city as receivercity , re.state as receiverstate, re.country as receivercountry, re.zipCode as receiverzip),(se.address as senderAddress,se.city as sendercity , se.state as senderstate , se.country as sendercountry , se.zipCode as senderzip , se.image as senderimage ,se.fName as senderfName, se.lName as senderlName )) 
FROM contacts as co
LEFT JOIN users as se ON( se.id = co.senderid )
LEFT JOIN users as re ON( re.id = co.receiverid )
where (senderid = 1 OR receiverid = 1)
```

-- is that selecting multiple fields on join table is not valid with or something else ?

I am unable to figure out the exact reason , basic prob. here is to select few fields based on if condition from user table based on join.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use aliases in the if statement it seems. I have just tested your query, and removing the aliases, resolves the issue.

`if(( co.senderid = 1) , ( re.image, re.fName, re.lName, re.address, re.city, re.state, re.country, re.zipCode),(se.address,se.city, se.state, se.country, se.zipCode, se.image,se.fName, se.lName )) AS mydata`

Edit: You should also add an alias to your entire IF so you don't get the expression as a column name :)

Edit 2: Sorry, I wrote too soon. You cannot select multiple rows like this in a select. You will have to write a subquery if you want that data or put an if for every column you need.

```
IF(co.senderid = 1, re.image, se.address,) as col1
IF(co.senderid = 1, re.fName, se.city) as col2
IF(co.senderid = 1, re.lName, se.state) as col3
IF(co.senderid = 1, re.address, se.country) as col4
```

And so on... You get the point :)

Comment: Thank you for figuring out the issue. I will check